# Syntax Error after JSONP request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

I'm trying to fetch the data of a JSONP, but it returns a Syntax error when the function is called. I'm really new to this topic and don't understand why. Probably because I didn't understand everything of JSONP requests. It would be nice if someone could help me out.

Executed code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://backpack.tf/api/IGetMarketPrices/v1?format=json&callback=JSONP&key=XXX&appid=730",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {format: "json"},
        type: "GET",
        jsonp: "response",
        jsonpCallback: "response",
        success: function( response ) {
          console.log( response ); // server response
        }
      });
```

(I had to censor my API key.)

Error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

The response is:

```
{"response":{"success":1,"current_time":1486000891,"items":{"AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)":{"last_updated":1485997229,"quantity":80,"value":1092},...
```

The first : is underlined by Chrome.

[Here](https://backpack.tf/api/docs/IGetMarketPrices) is the API documentation.

Comment: That means you do not have JSONP, you have JSON.

Comment: `The response is:` not JSONP - it's just JSON -perhaps backback.tf don't do "JSONP"

Comment: @Jaraomanda X but on the documentation, it says callback only JSONP.

Comment: your url says `callback=JSONP` ... your parameters say `jsonp: "response"` and `jsonpCallback: "response",` .... can you show what the "request" looks like in the network tab, i.e. what URL the request tries to fetch

Comment: That should be: `https://backpack.tf/api/IGetMarketPrices/v1?format=json&callback=JSONP&key=XXX&appid=730&response=response&format=json&_=1486002163138` (That's the source Chrome gives me for the error)

Comment: so set the proper callback name in the options

Comment: so you have `callback=JSONP` and `response=response` in the URL ... which parameter does the API expect?

Comment: try this ... remove `jsonp` and `jsonpCallback` parameters, and remove `callback=JSONP` from the url

Comment: @charlietfl would that be `jsonp: "JSONP"` then?

Comment: no...get rid of that and set it in `jsonpCallback` ... read $.ajax docs to understand difference

Comment: well, read the API documentation, surely there's some clue in there as to what your query should look like

Comment: @JaromandaX tried it. Still the same error. But URL changed to '`https://backpack.tf/api/IGetMarketPrices/v1?format=json&key=XXX&appid=730&callback=jQuery31108130174478341612_1486002405607&format=json&_=1486002405608`

Comment: @charlietfl I deleted the `jsonp: ...` part and changed `jsonpCallback: "JSONP"` but it still does not work.

Comment: @JaromandaX That's why I provided the link for the documentation either I'm stupid or there is none.

Comment: `That's why I provided the link for the documentation` - see answer and bathe in my glorious countenance :p

Answer (score 1):

From trial and error - impressive as I have no API key

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://backpack.tf/api/IGetMarketPrices/v1?format=jsonp&key=XXX&appid=730",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    type: "GET",
    success: function( response ) {
      console.log( response ); // server response
    }
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://backpack.tf/api/IGetMarketPrices/v1",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        format: 'jsonp',
        key: 'XXX',
        appid: 730
    },
    success: function( response ) {
      console.log( response ); // server response
    }
});
```

To explain... jQuery automatically adds a query parameter called `callback` on jsonp requests... as the API states that you need to define the callback name in a parameter called `callback`, you can let jQuery use the default value of `callback`

Then, jQuery creates a function with a long random name, and sets the value of the `callback` parameter to that function - so you don't have to worry about the `jsonp` or `jsonpCallback` parameters - defaults are good

I must be missing something basic, because this should work!

Comment: Wit that I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery31109337491141215399_1486002924271 is not defined`

Comment: I just noticed that is probably because the response now is wrapped in `jQuery31109337491141215399_1486002924271(...)` but I don't know why that is there now. Hope that helps.

Comment: found that out now aswell. However, this is changed by the `callback` if I understood it right. The API documentation tells me the only valid value for `callback` is `JSONP`. But if I enter that it also returns me a reference error. How could that be?

Comment: `The API documentation tells me the only valid value for callback is JSONP` no ... the callback parameter is only valid for JSONP requests

Comment: using the code in the answer, I get the URL = `https://backpack.tf/api/IGetMarketPrices/v1?&format=jsonp&key=XXX&appid=730&callback=jQuery112402136578559272766_1486004278949&_=1486004278950` ... the response is valid JSONP in the format `jQuery112402136578559272766_1486004278949({ data })` ...

Comment: @Jaromando X ... Ohhhhh I feel kind of stupid now... Wait gimme 10 minutes. I hope I can fix it by myself.

Comment: @Jaramando X After finally understanding the callback parameter, deleting the `success` part and setting `callback: "console.log"` works for me.

Comment: by the way, I'd recommend jQuery 2.1.3 at least

Comment: @Jaramonanda X Well yeah I guess I'm still dumm... Well... How do I trigger the success function?

Comment: the code in my answer should work ... without a valid API key I can only speculate - I can see the request and response look fine (for an error response) ... copy the code, add the API key, run it, check the console

Comment: Well it the error stays the same. `jQuery311010361242467299459_1486006438112` is not defined on the other server side and `callback` gets automatically set to that. So I still get the same error as mentioned in the beginning.

Comment: `is not defined on the other server side` what is this other server side? the function would need to exist on the client browser - is there something you've missed in the question about this code? Also, which version of jQuery?

Comment: I use Jquery 3.1.1 . What I meant (correct me if I'm wrong) ist that the function would need to be defined on the target location, not in my script. - Also, I still do not understand when the function defined in `success` is triggered. Could you explain?

Comment: no, that's not how JSONP works ... jquery creates the function for you, on the client browser page that calls $.ajax

Comment: look at this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/6cnxx4h8/1/ - see how it runs ... add your API key instead of XXX ... **DO NOT UPDATE THE FIDDLE OTHERWISE YOUR API KEY WILL BE "PUBLISHED", JUST CLICK RUN**

Comment: I don't know, I can't see your browser, I can't see the code, I can't see that you've accurately reproduced code that as far as I can tell will work (without an API key, who knows)

Comment: no result on the jsfiddle page. I'd feel comfortable sharing the key with you if there is a way to share it privately.

Comment: damn, you don't have enough rep to chat

Comment: which browser are you using ... no result, at all ... that is very odd

Comment: I am using Google Chrome

Comment: I just tried chrome ... still get `statusText: error
error: error` - which is expected output since I don't have an API key

Comment: @JaromandaX, I've given the OP access to chat (in case you both want to discuss more) http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134846/discussion-on-answer-by-jaromanda-x-syntax-error-after-jsonp-request